# Issue with Facebook integration in IOS App while user is trying to login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have integrated the Facebook SDK for signin into my app. 
When  a user tries to signin Facebook, it throws the below error asking us to submit for review (public profile, email and location).

This error is specifically thrown for city. Since public profile and email does not require review.
Where should I check in my app for permissions related to location/city.
Or is there ay configuration required for the same.

I am using the activeapp for analysing the active apps. Is this causing the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once  read [**facebook developer documentation**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit). Facebook clearly mention following :

> If your app asks for more than than **public_profile, email and user_friends** it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers.
>       The time to review your app is usually about 7 business days. Some extra-sensitive permissions, as noted below, can take up to 14 business days.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your app asked for permissions for which Facebook required to review your app. You have to submit your application for Facebook review. 
You can submit your app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit) for Facebook review.

For testing purpose you can add your testing Facebook account within app Roles as Tester.

Once Facebook review your app and approved, your app will work fine for all users.